# I would like to confirm my answer

Tags: arrays, search, sorting

"Consider an array with n elements. If we visit each element n times, how many total visits will there be?"

I need a little help on this question. What i got is n^(n). I need someone to confirm that it is either right or wrong.

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Visiting 3 elements three times each would result in 3*3 visits, or 9.

Visiting n elements n times each would result in n*n visits, or n^2

Answer (score 3):

No, it should be *n* × *n*. Suppose that *n* = 5. Then there are 5 elements:

```
1 // visited 5 times
2 // visited 5 times
3 // visited 5 times
4 // visited 5 times
5 // visited 5 times
```

5 + 5 + 5 + 5 + 5 = 5 × 5 = 25

Comment: actually I got that answer before i ended up with n^n.